# How to get cyrillic string from document

Tags: python, parsing

How to get cyrillic string from document?

I have fallowing code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.urlopen("http://habrahabr.ru/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
for topic in soup.findAll(True, 'topic'):
    print topic
    print
raw_input()
```

There is cyrillic words on the site but python displays wrong characters.

I will be very helpful for any help in this issue.

PS.

I changed

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
```

and still no results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data on the HTML page is encoded in UTF-8. It appears that you are printing it to your console, where sys.stdout.encoding is cp1251. That accounts for the rubbish that you are seeing.

Here are the results of inspecting the first 8 bytes of the first topic, using IDLE:

```
>>> raw = '\xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe'
>>> print raw.decode('utf8')
Алго
>>> print raw.decode('cp1251')
РђР»РіРѕ
>>>
```

Comment: But i what i need to do in my example? I tried to convert 
`page.read().decode('utf8')`
but no results...

Comment: Hmmmmmm it's very strange but only one item of these was normaly displayed... other items were in wrong characters...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.

I solve issue with this code:

```
print str(topic).decode('utf8')
```

Comment: I very much doubt that `str()` is required. `print topic.decode('utf8')` should suffice.

Comment: I guess it can be required in some situations since Python 3 renamed the unicode type to str and the old str type has been replaced by bytes.

Answer (score 0):

in django i solved it this way:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
print ("%s" % force_unicode(topic, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
```

so you can grab this function from django